# Синхронизация выполнения функций

Tags: javascript

Синхронизация в javascript. Например, есть три функции:

```
func1(function(){}); // асинхронная с callback
func2(function(){}); // асинхронная с callback
func3(); // синхронная возвращает true-false
```

Нужно, чтобы после того, как `func1` и `func2` вызвали свои callback, а
`func3` вернул `true`, вызвать функцию `func4`.

Как правильно и лучше всего это сделать, если ли стандартная техника для такого?

Comment: [_Promise_](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

Comment: @Grundy напишите, пожалуйста, вариант по канонам ES6/ES7 с использованием Promise. Мне интересно, ещё не копал их.

Comment: @Sergiks, не уверен, что мой вариант будет соответствовать канонам :-D

Comment: Так как асинхронная функция может быть реализована по разному, в том числе вызывая внутри асинхронную функцию которая уже может возвращать Promise или аналогичный объект из библиотек решение может сильно отличаться.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Вариант 1 - наиболее разумный - использовать *Promise* и *Deferred*.**

http://api.jquery.com/promise/

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/

http://api.jquery.com/deferred.promise/

Код:

```
var d1 = $.Deferred();
var d2 = $.Deferred();
var d3 = $.Deferred();

func1(function() { d1.notify(); });
func2(function() { d2.notify(); });
func3();
d3.notify();

$.when( d1, d2, d3 ).done(function () {
    // Выполнить результирующее действие.
});
```

**Вариант 2 - завести счетчик количества выполняемых функций** (не требует библиотек) и отслеживать выполнение в общем callback-е. Возможно также вместо счетчика использовать массив с именами функций.

```
var currentCallbacks = 0;
var expectedCallbacks = 3;

var commonCallback = function() {
    currentCallbacks++;
    if (currentCallbacks == expectedCallbacks) {
        // Выполнить результирующее действие.
    }
};

func1(function(){commonCallback();});
func2(function(){commonCallback();});
func3();
commonCallback();
```

**Вариант 3 - [_underscore.js имеет функцию `after`](http://underscorejs.ru/#after)**. Если библиотека уже подключена, можно использовать её функционал.

> Вернёт копию функции function, модифицированную таким образом, что она
>   будет запущена только после того, как будет вызвана count раз. Удобно
>   использовать при работе с асинхронными запросами, например, чтобы
>   убедиться, что все обращения к серверу завершились.

```
var commonCallback = _.after(3, function() {
    // Выполнить результирующее действие...
});

func1(function() { commonCallback(); });
func2(function() { commonCallback(); });
func3(); // Внутри должен перед выходом из функции вызываться commonCallback();

var functions = [func1, func2, func3];
var runProcess = function() {
  _.each(functions, function(func) {
      func();
  });
};

runProcess();
```

**Вариант 4 - построить цепочку вызовов, но убивает все плюсы параллелизма.**

```
func1(callback1);

function callback1()
{
    ...
    func2(callback2);
}

function callback2()
{
    ...
    func3();
    // Выполнить результирующее действие.
}
```

Comment: вот варианты вроде нормальные, но примеры для них кроме 4, кажется выдранные откуда-то и ничего общего с задачей в вопросе не имеют, например, во втором, в какой-то _this_ добавили свойства, ---используется какой-то объект _me_ нигде не объявленный--- в колбэках используется _this_ который может отличаться от того на который рассчитывается

Comment: **Критика:** Вариант 1 замедлит выполнение: вероятно, два асинхронных вызова могут выполняться параллельно, а тут навязывается последовательность. Вариант 2 почему-то вводит контекст и неиспользуемый параметр `resp`. Варианты 3 и 4 предлагают подключать здоровенную библиотеку для изолированной триваильной задачи.

Comment: @Sergiks, ну 4 хотя бы соответствует задаче, к тому же jQuery наверняка уже подключен :-)

Comment: @Grundy не стоит *предполагать*. По-англ. `assume = to make an 'ass' out of 'u' and 'me'` )  В вопросе не упомянуты фреймворки и библиотеки.

Comment: @Sergiks, поменялся порядок вариантов и мои комментарии превратились в тыкву :-D

Comment: @Grundy, Ок, скорректировал + поменял варианты местами. Извиняюсь за "превращение комментариев в тыкву", но надо же исправлять недостатки? По поводу лишних контекстов - частично выдираю из документации примеры и переделываю. Немного невнимательно просмотрел.

Comment: @LbISS, можете по третьему варианту подробнее расписать, не совсем пойму как это должно работать? который с _underscore_

Comment: А jquery when(), он кроссплатформенный(на мобильных устройствах везде работает)? 
Выглядит самым интересным вариантом.

Comment: @Grundy, немного расширил код. По сути, это вариант 2, просто с использованием функционала underscore.

Comment: @LbISS, очень плохой пример для _underscore_ привели, `$.ajax()` уже возвращает Promise которые в jQuery, поэтому нет смысла делать городушки с другой библиотекой

Comment: @Grundy, там любая асинхронная работа. Я не в курсе что у автора внутри функций. Пожалуй, сделаю аналогично 1-ому примеру.

Comment: да, так лучше стало

Answer (score 2):

Два варианта, довольно простые, «в лоб» – минимум кода, без дополнительных библиотек, обёрток и требований поддержки новых стандартов JavaScript:

---

**Счётчик**, который инкрементировать после выполнения каждой из функций, и проверять сразу, равен ли он уже числу функций (3)?

```
var done = 0; // счётчик завершённых задач

func1(function(){ ..; areWeDone()}); // асинхронная с callback
func2(function(){ ..; areWeDone()}); // асинхронная с callback
func3(){ ..; areWeDone()}; // синхронная возвращает true-false

function areWeDone() {
  if( ++done === 3} {     // все три выполнены 
  } else {                // ещё нет 
  }
}
```

---

Чуть сложнее: завести **битовую маску**, где каждый бит означает выполнение одной из функций. Будет точно известно, какие именно ф-ии уже выполнились, какие ещё нет. Можно строить более развитую логику.

```
var done = 0; // биты 0,1,2 - готовность от func1, func2, func3
func1(function(){ ..; areWeDone(0)}); // асинхронная с callback
func2(function(){ ..; areWeDone(1)}); // асинхронная с callback
func3(){ ..; areWeDone(2)}; // синхронная возвращает true-false

function areWeDone(bit) {
  done = done | 1<<bit;   // устанавливаем очередной бит
                          // и проверяем остальные:
  if( done & 7 === 7) {   // - все три выполнены 
  } else {                // - ещё нет 
  }
}
```

Comment: а можно было просто +1 делать и проверить done == 3 :-)

Comment: можно, точно! : )  Я из логики одной своей штуки это вспомнил – там были варианты частичного выполнения.

Comment: кстати - похоже ошибка - все три выполнены это `111` - три бита же

Comment: и еще можно дополнить, что в первом варианте - нельзя отследить порядок, в котором выполнились функции, а во втором - каждый бит соответствует конкретной задаче

Comment: `done & 7` :-D блин, а я думал 11 он как бинарное число воспримет :-) можно вот так тогда: `done & 0b111`

Comment: Исправил биты, спасибо! `0b111` это, конечно, `7`.  Порядок, кажется, для ТС неважен. Эк вас, @Grundy, ES6 прельстил )) Запись `0b111` только в нём появилась. На IE не заработает : )

Comment: Ээээх :-) в IE и `0o` не работает. Я так понял там работает только 0 лидирующий и `0x`

Answer (score 2):

Еще вариант с использованием [*Promise*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). Подойдет если используемые функции действительно асинхронные и сами не возвращают *Promise* или аналогов из используемых библиотек.

Для использования нужно обернуть используемые функции в объект Promise:

1. Вариант для функций с callback

   ```
   var p1 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
     func1(function() {
       ...
       resolve(); // говорим, что все завершилось успешно. В случае неудачи нужно вызывать reject
     }); // ассинхронная с callback
   });
   ```
2. Для синхронной функции которая возвращает значение, которое нужно проверить

   ```
   var p = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
     if (func3() == condition) { // если условие выполняется
       resolve(); // говорим, что все завершилось успешно.
     } else { //если нет
       reject(); // говорим, что все завершилось неудачно.
     }    
   });
   ```
3. Для синхронной функции: [`Promise.resolve(func())`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve)

После оборачивания в объекты для ожидания результата всех нужно использовать [*Promise.all*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

```
Promise.all([p1, p2, ...])
```

Данная функция вернет Promise которые перейдет в статус fulfilled, т.е. завершен успешно, когда *все* Promise переданные в массиве будут иметь статус *fulfilled*

Тогда с помощью [метода.then](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) можно добавить обработчик

```
Promise.all(...).then(
     function(){ ... },//функция которая выполнится если статус _fulfilled_
     function(){} //функция которая выполнится если статус _rejected_
)
```

Пример:

```js
function func1(c) {
  setTimeout(c, 100);
}

function func2(c) {
  setTimeout(c, 10);
}

function func3() {
  return true;
}
var p1 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  func1(function() {
    output('1');
    resolve();
  }); // ассинхронная с callback
});
var p2 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  func2(function() {
    output('2');
    resolve();
  }); // ассинхронная с callback
});
var p3 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  if (func3()) {
    output('3');
    resolve(); // синхронная возвращает true-false
  } else {
    reject();
  }
});

Promise.all([p1, p2, p3]).then(function() {
  output('All done');
});

function output(text) {
  console.log(text);
  document.getElementById('res').innerHTML += text + '<br />';
}
```

```html
<div id="res"></div>
```